# Byte array character encoding for proper transmission of PDF (binary) content via HTTP

Tags: http, pdf, encoding

I'm in the process of migrating a web application from Tomcat8/Java8 to Tomcat10/Java11.  I worked through the javax vs jakarta issues.  Currently, I am debugging PDF and XLS response content.  The program code (JSP) I have been using for well over 15 years to send PDF (et al) back to a browser is now being received by the browser as corrupt content.

By process of elimination I have found that the (PDF) byte array generated by the utilities is valid when it is saved to a file on the server.  This is also true for XLS content.  But when that same byte array is returned to a browser, the resulting content is corrupt.
a) None of the code has changed.
b) When the server side byte array is saved to a server side file, the result is valid.
c) The only thing that has changed is the platform the code is running on.

I suspect the byte array is encoded differently in Java11, that the java.io packages properly handle the byte array when saving to a file on the server, but the byte array is not suitably encoded for a response to a browser. Does anyone have any insight on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint. The problem was resolved after recognizing PDF and XLS are considered binary content, not ASCII. The original implementation (Tomcst 8) was using the JSP member "out"(PrintWriter) to send the content. For Tomcat 10, I used the ServletOutputStream from the "response". I do not know why it "out" worked in Java 8.